# Javascript autoselect dropdown menus debugging error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where running the following code in the Chrome Javascript console throws the following error: `Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined`

Did I not instantiate the function properly? I am confused as to what I am doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('select[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownListSources"]').first().val("Plant/Unit Seed File");
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('select[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownListEquipmentTypes"]').first().val("Plant");
  }, 4000)
  document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonImportNow').click();
})
```

Comment: Did youve included http://jquery.com ???

Comment: jquery.com? I'm running the code in my browser console

Comment: jquery is an external library, so when you run this code in your browser console it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying in the comment, you need to have `jquery` referenced to use the library. Unless you are stopped on a breakpoint on a page with a `jquery` reference, the console of your browser won't be able to use the functionality provided by `jquery` or any other external libraries.

If you look at the snippet below, you can see that there is a `jquery` script tag. There are still javascript errors being thrown, but the error `Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined` is no longer being thrown because of the `jquery` reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('select[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownListSources"]').first().val("Plant/Unit Seed File");
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('select[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DropDownListEquipmentTypes"]').first().val("Plant");
  }, 4000)
  document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ButtonImportNow').click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation! I am totally new to jquery and javascript. How should I run it including the jquery library?